Apache2 stops serving HTTP pages at random times during the day, but not HTTPS
I've been noticing my websites are going down pretty frequently at times for the last few weeks, only sometimes but after a while they would be back up and running.
Until now, I attributed this problem to some cloud-flare maintenance and didn't think much of It, but I just noticed that request to even my DynDNS from my internet provider, which exposes my server to the internet does not go trough cloudflare, all also fail. Interestingly only when I use HTTP, but not HTTPS.
This is very much a server issue, since not even directory listings or accessing a in-existent path which should return 404 works.
Here is an example of a request I send to my server:
GET http://mainsite.ro/

User-Agent: firefox
Accept: *
Host: mainsite.ro
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, identity

And my server replied with:
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Cache-control: no-cache

My Apache2 logs:
[Tue Nov 05 13:05:51.861763 2024] [php:warn] [pid 299659] [client 162.158.79.58:31474] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in /var/www/codrutsoft.com/_data/database/netapps/file-bin/index.php on line 4
[Tue Nov 05 13:28:46.363513 2024] [pagespeed:error] [pid 299558] [mod_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0 @299558] PageSpeed Serf fetch failure rate extremely high; only 2 of 11 recent fetches fully successful; is fetching working?
[Tue Nov 05 14:48:20.259543 2024] [autoindex:error] [pid 199451] [client 86.126.67.12:35638] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/mainsite.ro/www/img/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Nov 05 14:54:10.553472 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 500788] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Nov 05 14:54:10.750487 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1094019] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 05 14:54:10.750587 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1094019] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Nov 05 14:54:38.022673 2024] [autoindex:error] [pid 1094020] [client 86.126.67.12:59847] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/mainsite.ro/www/img/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Nov 05 14:56:07.603159 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1094019] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Nov 05 14:56:07.808091 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1105218] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 05 14:56:07.808175 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1105218] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

And an example HTTPs request, which always seems to work is:
GET http://mainsite.ro/

User-Agent: firefox
Accept: *
Host: mainsite.ro
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, identity

With the response of
Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2024 13:11:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.13.35.2-0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, s-maxage=10
Content-Length: 897
Content-Type: text/html

Additionally accessing my site directly via also IP does not work, but accessing the local IP (192.168.1.101) works just fine.
I have no idea what could be causing this, but It's a rather frustrating issue since nothing in the logs explains why this might be happening.

What do you get in the logs if you raise the LogLevel?

@u1686_grawity Nothing related to what could cause this, and I can't test It since It started working again. The only question is how long for

Test it by raising the log level now and leaving it raised until it happens again.

"GET http://mainsite.ro/" is not an https request. If your outgoing HTTP fails at the same time as incoming, this suggests an issue on the network, not on your host.

I think I may have figured out the cause of the issue.
As @symcbean suggested, this issue would seem to be caused by the network not the host. And it was rather strange that I could access the server locally but not using my public IP.
So my guess is that since I have my Linux host configured as a DMZ Server in the router configuration, a UPnP device on my network requested port 80 for Itself and this caused it to no longer go to my server.
To combat this, I set a port forwarding rule of the port 80 directly to my server, and for now everything seems to work.
The main thing that caused me to believe this could be the problem, is I tried to add the forwarding rule to port 80 and the router administration panel informed me that port 80 was already bound, but there were no rules set by me. Also this would explain why HTTPs worked, since It's on a different port, port 443.
I will see the following days If the issue arises again and will provide more details if so.
